# Do calling of String methods directly also store that String in String pool?

Tags: java, string

I have stored password in char array and while retriving them back I am calling `String.ValueOf(char[] array)` method directly . Do this thing will store the formed String in String pool. If yes, How can we store hardcoded passwords more securely without the use of Hashing and encryption techniques?

Example:

```
public class TestUser {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      User u1 = new User();

      System.out.println("User Name is "+u1.getUserId());
      System.out.println("Password is "+String.valueOf(u1.getPassword()));

   }
}
```

Please explain.

Comment: "Do this thing will store the formed String in String pool " No.

Comment: Ideally, your app should have no idea what your users' password are.  That call to `ui.getPassword()` should be returning encrypted/garbled characters and not a plain text password.  You should be storing only the encrypted passwords.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks

Comment: As it is said in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords), a side-effect of using `char[]` in place of `String`is that you limit the risk of printing your password somewhere in readable format.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Acutally , I am trying to use this thing for JDBC connections and the ui.getPassword() method is returing an char array .

In my application it is very hectic process to implement encoding techniques.

Comment: @AndyTurner Where did you find the info? I foud in the oracle doc that `String.valueOf returns a newly allocated String that represent the array`, so since we initialize it it should end in the String pool?

Comment: @Nathan I have already read that topic , but my concern was that the direct calling of String methods will store the formed String in String pool or in heap .

Comment: @Nathan strings don't go into the string pool unless 1) they are compile-time constants; 2) you explicitly call `intern()` on them.

Comment: @luk2302 This is not a case where I am storing the passwords of users , this thing I am asking is for only storing hardcoded password just in case of JDBC connections . That's it , it has nothing to do with user passwords .

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for the precision.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`String.valueOf(char[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-char:A-) doesn't state that it [interns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--) the resulting string, but doesn't state that it *doesn't*, either. In general, if the method doesn't *say* it interns the string, I'd feel comfortable assuming it doesn't.

The current implementation in Oracle's JDK does not, it looks like this:

```
public static String valueOf(char data[]) {
    return new String(data);
}
```

You could, of course, avoid any ambiguity by using `new String(char[])` directly.

**That said, ideally, don't use a `String` at all**, since the `char[]` contents are *copied* and you can't then overwrite the copy to clear out the password chars when you're done with them (without resorting to reflection). Instead, **as soon** as you get the `char[]` from your UI layer, run your password hashing algorithm on it and immediately overwrite the contents of the `char[]`, and then validate the hashed password against the stored copy (e.g., in the DB, etc.).

---

Just because someone's going to point it out: *Printing out* the password is probably the larger security concern than whether the password is interned. But this looks like test code... :-)